# What will be the icon sizes and names of the icon to be used in Xcode for deployment on iOS6 and iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I have app which i build when i tested this on xcode4 it works fine with 72*72 icon it does not show anything.But Client Tested this on xcode 5 it showed him error mising icon dimensions file 76*76 etc any idea how to solve this issue and add all the icons with the file name used for both.

I have searched i get but they only tell for separately for iOS 6 and iOS7 what if deploy for both how to give icon name like if we have 72*72 and also 76*76 what will be there name in xcode to be used so that icon display on app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check the following links:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/09/17/tutorial-getting-started-with-ios-7/
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

in your info plist reference all icon files:
under the Icon files key

(below is for iPhone. non retina, retina AND ios7)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>App_ICON_57px.png</string>
    <string>App_ICON_114px.png</string>
    <string>App_ICON_120px.png</string>
</array>
</plist>
```